# Delete multiple keys from memcached

Tags: java, memcached

I have two tables, the data of which are cached using memcached.
Both the tables are using the same memcached server.
Ex:

ABC table class:

```
public class ABC {
    public int abc;
    public Data data;
    public static final NAMESPACE = "ABC";

    public String getKey() {
        return NAMESPACE + abc;
    }

    public void cacheData() {
        String server = "127.0.0.1:11211";
        MemcachedClient client = new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(), AddrUtil.getAddresses(servers));
        client.set(getKey(),data);
    }
}
```

XYZ table class:

```
public class XYZ {
    public int xyz;
    public Data data;
    public static final NAMESPACE = "XYZ";

    public String getKey() {
        return NAMESPACE + xyz;
    }

    public void cacheData() {
        String server = "127.0.0.1:11211";
        MemcachedClient client = new MemcachedClient(new BinaryConnectionFactory(), AddrUtil.getAddresses(servers));
        client.set(getKey(),data);
    }
}
```

Now multiple data are being cached in the same memcached server for both the tables. And I cud also remove keys one at a time. But how do I delete the entire cache only for one particular table i.e. if I want to delete cache only for XYZ table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove multiple keys from `memcached` in one go. Just do it separately.

If you have to do that, then you're probably misusing `memcached`.

Comment: The thing is I am deleting multiple data from the table using commands like this `delete from table where id=?`. Then, what should be the appropriate process of updating the cache entries?